# Organizing positioned LIs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to organize a list by date, but the `<li>` elements have `position: absolute` and are not displayed in their DOM order. What should I do?

Here is my code (also live at http://jsfiddle.net/CQ3gg/261/):

```
var hli = $('ul li').height();
var wli = $('ul li').width();
var tops = 0;
var lefts = 0;

$('ul li').each(function(i, el){    
    $(el).css({ top: tops });
    tops += hli;
});


var tt = true;

$(".teste").click(function(){
    if(tt == true){
        $("ul li").sort(function(a,b){
            return new Date($(a).attr("data-date")) > new Date($(b).attr("data-date"));
        }).each(function(){
            $("ul").prepend(this);
        });

         tt = false;
    }else if(tt == false){
        $("ul li").sort(function(a,b){
            return new Date($(a).attr("data-date")) < new Date($(b).attr("data-date"));
        }).each(function(){
            $("ul").prepend(this);
        });

        tt = true;
    }   
});
```

Comment: Don't hesitate if you have any question

Comment: Move the loop that set the `top` properties inside the click handler.

Comment: Why are you using `position: absolute` in the first place?

Comment: And what's the point of the `tt` variable? It seems like you're using it alternate between something, but to what end I have no idea.

Comment: The layout I'm developing needs to be absolutely positioned ...

Comment: Then reposition the elements by changing their `top` css property, instead of trying to sort the DOM tree.

Comment: the variable tt is used to do a scan where he will arrange by date ascending and descending

Comment: but how do I put it back with the new order?

Comment: What date format are you using? mm/dd/yyyy?

Comment: You are from Brazil, does not know the format? Anyway, the format is from Brazil. Does it matter? is not mm/dd/yy... is dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: Yes, it does matter. JavaScript will not intepret that correctly. And although I'm from Brazil, you date values are ambiguous, it could be that you were using the month first to get correct results from js. I'm trying to help you here, there's no reason to raise your tone.

Comment: hahaha, sorry .. It was not the intention of raising the tone but was an air of irony funny, really sorry I misunderstood ...

Comment: No problem. Added an answer, I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something similar to what you're already doing at the top of your code (example not considering descending order sort):

```
$(".teste").click(function(){
    var tops = 0;
    $("ul li").sort(function(a,b){
        return new Date($(a).attr("data-date")) > new Date($(b).attr("data-date"));
    }).each(function(){
        $(this).css({ top: tops });
        tops += hli; // assumes previously defined hli
    });
});
```

You should also use `YYYY-MM-DD` as the date format, to avoid parsing problems with `new Date`. See a live example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sYa5r/).

Comment: My problem is a little more complex. But it already helped me a lot!! Thank you ...